# Cython initialize matrix with zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

**Description**

I simply want to create a matrix of `rows x cols` that is filled with `0`s. Always working with numpy I thought using `np.zeros` as described [in the docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html) is the easiest:

```
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def f1():
    cdef:
        int dim = 40000
        int i, j
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] mat = np.zeros([40000, 40000], dtype=DTYPE)
        
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            mat[i, j] = 1
```

Then I compared this using the arrays in c:

```
def f2():
    cdef:
        int dim = 40000
        int[40000][40000] mat
        int i, j
    
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            mat[i][j] = 1
```

The numpy version took `3 secs` on my pc whereas the c version only took`2.4e-5 secs`. However when I return the array from `f2()` I noticed it is not zero filled (of course here it can't be, `i==j` however when not filling it it won't return a 0 array either). How can this be done in cython. I know in regular C it would be like: `int arr[n][m] = {};`.

**Question**

How can the c array be filled with `0s`? (I would go for numpy instead if there is something obvious wrong in my code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to be writing code like this:

1. `int[40000][40000] mat` generates a 6 gigabyte array on the stack (assuming 4 byte ints). Typically maximum stack sizes are of the order of a few Mb. I have no idea how this isn't crashing your PC.
2. > However when I return the array from f2() [...]

   The array you have allocated is completely local to the function. From a C point of view you cannot return it since it ceases to exist after the function has finished. I think Cython may convert it to a (nested) Python list for you. This requires a slow copy element-by-element and is not what you want.

For what you're doing here you're **much** better just using Numpy.

---

Cython doesn't support a good equivalent of the C `arr = {}` so if you do want initialize sensible, small C arrays you need to use of one:

1. loops,
2. `memset` (which you can `cimport` from `libc.string`),
3. Create a typed memoryview of it and do `memview[:,:] = 0`

---

> The numpy version took 3 secs on my pc whereas the c version only took2.4e-5 secs.

This kind of difference usually suggests that the C compiler has optimized some code out (by detecting that the result is unused). It is unlikely to be a genuine speed-up.

Comment: Think your last edit is why it didn't give an error for the stack, adding `return mat[0]` at the end of the function does make the code crash hehe. Thanks for mentioning!